# ItemDataBound in Nested repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a Nested repeater in my web form and I put two ObjectDataSource for each repeater.

I have this method in my repositiry:

```
 public IQueryable<TourDate> GetById(int Id)
{
    return model.TourDates.Where(e => e.TourId == Id);
}
```

I need to Set ItemDataBound event .

I write this code for ItemDataBound event:

```
 protected void RptTourDetail_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem ||
    e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
{
var dataItem = e.Item.DataItem;
ObjectDataSource ObjectDataSource1 = (ObjectDataSource)e.Item.FindControl("ObjectDataSource1");
    ObjectDataSource1.SelectParameters["TourId"].DefaultValue = dataItem.TourId;
 }


}
```

but it dosent recognize TourId at last line.I think something wrong is there with this

```
var dataItem = e.Item.DataItem;
```

does anyone have any idea whats the problem?

some explanation about projcet if needed:

here is my model
[image]

and html:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ODSTTitle" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetById"     TypeName="ATourRep">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="Id"  QueryStringField="CID" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server"  SelectMethod="GetById" TypeName="ATourDateRep">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>

<div class="container" id="TourDetail">

        <asp:Repeater ID="RptTourDetail" runat="server" DataSourceID="ODSTTitle" ItemType="Tour" EnableViewState="false" OnItemDataBound="RptTourDetail_ItemDataBound">
            <HeaderTemplate>

                <ul>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li>


<img src="<%# Item.TImgUrl %>" alt="Alternate Text" class="img-responsive" />
                    <div class="row">


                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <%-- NestedRepeater --%>
                            <p>

                                <%# Item.TourId %>

                            </p>
                            <asp:Repeater ItemType="TourDate" ID="RptTourNested" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <h2>

                                   <%# Item.TourStartDate %>
                                         </h2>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </div>


                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <%-- This Column works correctly --%>
                            <h4>
                                <%# Item.TName %>
                            </h4>
                            <p>
                                <%# Item.TDes %>
                            </p>
                        </div>


                        <div class="col-md-3">c</div>
                    </div>

                </li>

            </ItemTemplate>

            <FooterTemplate>
                </ul>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

    </div>
```

Comment: Does renaming "ObjectDataSource1" to another name work??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There's conflict in variable's name with control's name. Try to Rename

```
    ObjectDataSource ObjectDataSource1 = (ObjectDataSource)e.Item.FindControl("ObjectDataSource1");
ObjectDataSource1.SelectParameters["TourId"].DefaultValue = dataItem.TourId;
```

> To

```
    ObjectDataSource objTourDataSource= (ObjectDataSource)e.Item.FindControl("ObjectDataSource1");
objTourDataSource.SelectParameters["TourId"].DefaultValue = dataItem.TourId;
```

Comment: I tried to. but it doesn't changed. still it doesn't recognize TourId . Really thanks for your care

Comment: I think there is some problem in dataItem . it dosen't recognize fields like TourId and other . even befor objectdatasource Initialization

Comment: What does your method "GetById" return? if its a List<T> Then try this:
`T dataRow = e.Item.DataItem as T;
                if (dataRow != null)
                {
                    var tourId = dataRow.TourId.ToString();
                }`

Comment: it was IQueryable    public IQueryable<TourDate> GetById(int Id)
    {
        return model.TourDates.Where(e => e.TourId == Id);
    } _ but you have a good suggestion. maybe change to list would help. but how I should change it to list??

Comment: `public List<TourDate> GetById(int Id)
    {
        return model.TourDates.Where(e => e.TourId == Id).ToList();
    } ` i changed to list like this but im not sure it shouldent be <TourDate> object. any help plzzz. any way you helped me alot. really appreciate

Comment: Is TourDate an object? And does "TourDate" contain TourId?

Comment: Does the repeater bind List<TourDate> ? If yes, then the method i suggested should work. Give it a try.

Comment: yes TourDate is a table which entity frame work make an object of it. yes its object. and yes TourDate contain TourId. yes Nested repeater should bind to that Iqueryable which I should change it to list. i should try .

Comment: there is this Error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`  My changes is like this: ` public List<TourDate> GetById(int Id)
    {
        return model.TourDates.Where(e => e.TourId == Id).ToList();
    }  `       `TourDate dataRow = e.Item.DataItem as TourDate;
            ObjectDataSource objTourDataSource = (ObjectDataSource)e.Item.FindControl("ObjectDataSource1");
            objTourDataSource.SelectParameters["Id"].DefaultValue = dataRow.TourId.ToString();` I'm really sorry Bikash

Comment: In which line do you get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error?

Comment: in this one :  `objTourDataSource.SelectParameters["Id"].DefaultValue = dataRow.TourId.ToString();  `

Comment: because i force` e.Item.DataItem ` to be TourDate then it's null so it has that error. do you have any idea?

Comment: thank you @bikash it solved. the problem was that I didnt put the object data source nested in reapeter. thank you really for all your helps.